# How to pass HTML of a div to a textarea automatically and in real time?

Tags: jquery

I have made a simple project, from an editor, with basic functions of adding `bold`, `italic`, `h1`, `h2`, `p`, among other features.

All these functions are added to the text that is written in an editable div

```
<div id="editor" class="editor"contenteditable></div>
```

Now I need to pass all the information that has the editable div yet textarea, so that I can then insert in the database that information and validate with PHP.

I have done the following but it does not show what is written automatically and in real time

http://jsfiddle.net/02fvzn5b/13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to update in realtime, you have to attach an event listener to the div:

```js
$(function() {
  let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
  htmlDiv.on("keyup", function(e) { // <-- add the html every time it updates
   $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html())
  });
  $("#textarea").html(htmlDiv.html()) // <-- add it once at the beginning
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor" class="editor" contenteditable><span>Hello</span></div>

<!-- The textarea hide, with display none; -->
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks my friend, I have one last question on a similar subject if you have time for me, can you help me with some idea about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376925/how-to-see-the-generated-html-code-in-the-same-editable-div-of-my-editor

Answer (score 0):

change your function to listen to the correct event on your div like this:

```
$("#editor").on("keyup", function(){
    let textDiv = $("#editor").html();
    let htmlDiv = $("#editor").html();
    $("#textarea").val(textDiv);
});
```

you have to work around some formatting and filtering, but I believe you mention you'll do that with PHP.